# How to list down an array from JSON object with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

The jSON object is given below to keep so many product names and their following data:

```
var buyOnlineJSON={
      "CourseDetail": [
        {
          "ProductName": "product1",
          "productID": "DE34A",
          "crseDes": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.",
          "courseList": {
            "crseID1": "course1",
            "crseID2": "course2",
            "crseID3": "course3",
            "crseID4": "course4",
            "crseID5": "course5",
            "crseID6": "course6"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
```

I am able to list out following objects: `ProductName`, `productID`, `crseDes`, with following jQuery code

```
for(var i=0;i<buyOnlineJSON.CourseDetail.length;i++)
{
    console.log(Object.keys(buyOnlineJSON.CourseDetail[i].courseList));
    $("#buyOnline ol").append(
            '<li>' + 
                '<img src="images/book.png" />' + 
                '<a>' +
                    buyOnlineJSON.CourseDetail[i].ProductName +
                '</a>' +
                '<p>' +
                    buyOnlineJSON.CourseDetail[i].crseDes +
                '</p>'
            '</li>'
    );
}
```

How to list out `courseList` array from it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `for-in` loop to iterate over the properties in an object.

```
for(var i=0;i<buyOnlineJSON.CourseDetail.length;i++)
{
    console.log(Object.keys(buyOnlineJSON.CourseDetail[i].courseList));
    var courses = '<ol>';
    var courseList = buyOnlineJSON.CourseDetail[i].courseList;
    for (var id in courseList) {
        if (courseList.hasOwnProperty(id)) {
            courses += '<li>' + courseList[id] + '</li>';
        }
    }
    courses += '</ol>';
    $("#buyOnline ol").append(

        '<li>'
            +
            '<img src="images/book.png" />'
            +
            '<a>'
            +
            buyOnlineJSON.CourseDetail[i].ProductName
            +
            '</a>'                                 
            +
            '<p>'
            +
            buyOnlineJSON.CourseDetail[i].crseDes
            +
            '</p>'
            +
            courses
            +

        '</li>'

    );

}
```

Comment: Thank you for the instant replay.Like this i can list out both `keys` and `values` ryt

Comment: Right. If you want to display the keys, they're in `id`.

Comment: instead of ordered list in `courseList` unordered list is fine. Thank you again.

Comment: Of course, I just had to pick something for my example. The actual formatting is entirely up to you.

Answer (score 2):

You need to access `courseList` object in `CourseDetail` array before you assess the members of `courseList` i.e. `crseID1`

```
buyOnlineJSON.CourseDetail[i].courseList.crseID1
```

**Edit** based on comments, You can go through the object key and value of courseList using for loop

```
for (var key in buyOnlineJSON.CourseDetail[i].courseList) {
   alert(' name=' + key + ' value=' + buyOnlineJSON.CourseDetail[i].courseList[key]);
```

Comment: `buyOnlineJSON.CourseDetail[i].courseList` array will be a dynamic array. It will vary with objects in it for each product. so i want it to list down dynamically.

Comment: Thanks @Barmar, I wanted to use the one on loop

Answer (score 0):

try this out

```
buyOnlineJSON.CourseDetail[0].courseList.crseID1
```

the result will be

```
"course1"
```

hope that helps.

Comment: He wants to list all the courses, not just a specific one.

Comment: buyOnlineJSON.CourseDetail[0].courseList this will list all the courses

Comment: But that's an object, not an HTML string.

Answer (score 0):

use inner loop like this.

```
for(var i=0;i<buyOnlineJSON.CourseDetail.length;i++)
{
    var currentCourseList = buyOnlineJSON.CourseDetail[i].courseList;
    var strHTMLCourseList = '';
    for(var key in currentCourseList)
    {
        strHTMLCourseList += '<p>' + currentCourseList[key] + '</p>';   // Use here own html to display.
    }

    $("#buyOnline ol").append(
            '<li>' + 
                '<img src="images/book.png" />' + 
                '<a>' +
                    buyOnlineJSON.CourseDetail[i].ProductName +
                '</a>' +
                '<p>' +
                    buyOnlineJSON.CourseDetail[i].crseDes +
                '</p>' +
                strHTMLCourseList
            '</li>'
    );

}
```